# How do I unit test exception handlers that have system calls in the try body?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

```
 public static string GetComputername() {
        try {
            return Environment.MachineName;
        } catch {
            return string.Empty; // make sure this never ever fails
        }
    }
```

I'm faced with unit testing the above code. Is there some magic in coercing the system to toss an exception from the `Environment` call? I could make changes to the method so that I can get the coverage I want, but I'm not too sure about that either... Any ideas?

Comment: `static`s are in most cases a bad design principle. And one of the reasons is the lack of testing...

Comment: Is it me or this static does not change a thing?

Comment: You could use something like fakes and shims to intercept the call to `Environment.MachineName` (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b49e9f5d-0e57-46b1-8ced-f3231db5e813/cannot-find-a-shim-for-systemenvironmentmachinename-etc?forum=vsunittest), or you could inject something along the lines of `Func<string>` as a resolver, rather than wrap the call to `Environment.MachineName` directly.

Comment: As a general rule: you should only catch those exceptions which you _expect_ and which you _know_ what the right way to handle them is. You don't need a unit test to know that your `GetComputername()` method is flawed; it's flawed by design, because you have a blanket `catch` clause rather than catching some specific exception(s) that you prepared to deal with. If you know what exception to expect, this makes testing easier: you either know how to cause it from the actual API call, or you can mock it.

Comment: My opinion: 1) static are terrible to test but here you can't help, 2) properties _shouldn't_ throw but again you can't help, 3) you should never ever catch _all_. Here you know it _may_ (remotely) be InvalidOperationException. Catch just that. 4) Don't be code coverage addicted, you don't really need to write a test for everything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several aspects to answering this question:

1. Whitebox-Testing

If you realy want to make sure that the control-flow works as you would expect it, you would have to wrap the environment in a seperate class with an interface.. if you do that, you can Mock away the 'MachineName' call and simulate the normal and errror behaviour. This form of testing is very close to the code and takes a lot of effort to maintain if some minor thing changes in the implementation.

2. Unit Testing

Here you want to test the behaviour of the method from the outside (without testing line-by-line) if you do this you will find it hard to test the error case, because static calls are not mockable... you might want to test the normal case and in the other cases... so what (your decision)

3. Integration Testing

Here you really won't bother on implementation details only if the general stuff works as expected ("there is a name of some kind returned in the function that uses this")

The first part takes a lot of effort because you need to wrap everything, and in this case it might seem a little to much of work for that simple code.. but you need to decide which level of granularity you want write tests for...

This would be the wrapper:

```
public interface ISystemWrapper
{
    string MachineName();
}

public class SystemWrapper : ISystemWrapper
{
    public string MachineName()
    {
        return Environment.MachineName;
    }
}
```

You would modify the class like this:

```
public class ToTest
{
    public static ISystemWrapper SysWrapper = new SystemWrapper();

    public static string GetComputername()
    {
        try
        {
            return SysWrapper.MachineName();
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty; // make sure this never ever fails
        }
    }
}
```

And then mock the SysWrapper in your test

Comment: Very well done answer.  The way that static classes ripple across the code base hurts.  The only way to prevent it is to do what you've done here and nip it off before it creeps in.

Answer (score 0):

If you can mock `Environment` you can make a property that throws with no problem.

```
using System;

namespace TestThrowExceptionInProperty
{
    class Thrower {
        public int CheckMe {get{ throw new NotImplementedException (); }}
    }

    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var thrower = new Thrower ();
            int bye = thrower.CheckMe;
            Console.WriteLine(bye);
        }
    }
}
```